# Are tags supported in YouTube API?

Tags: ios, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm working on an iOS app that will let you start a live YouTube broadcast. I would like to add tags to this broadcast.

Looking at this page on the API documentation, I noticed that it is possible to set a value for the `snippet.tags[]` property, which seems to be exactly what I need. When I look at `GTLYouTubeLiveBroadcastSnippet.h`, however; I see the following properties:

```
@interface GTLYouTubeLiveBroadcastSnippet : GTLObject

@property (retain) GTLDateTime *actualEndTime;

@property (retain) GTLDateTime *actualStartTime;

@property (copy) NSString *channelId;

@property (retain) GTLDateTime *publishedAt;

@property (retain) GTLDateTime *scheduledEndTime;

@property (retain) GTLDateTime *scheduledStartTime;

@property (retain) GTLYouTubeThumbnailDetails *thumbnails;

@property (copy) NSString *title;
```

But I don't see anything regarding tags. Google folks--is it possible to create a live stream and add tags?? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API documentation you're referring to pertains to regular YouTube videos; YouTube live broadcasts have a different data model as far as the API is concerned. Unfortunately, the tags field is not exposed for reading or writing for live broadcasts directly.

There is a way around this, however. Once you've created your liveBroadcast object, you then take the videoID that's returned and use it in regular data API calls ... specifically, you'll want to use the videos/update endpoint and add in the snippet.tags data there (note that, for a valid update call, you'll be required to also once again set the snippet.title and snippet.categoryId).

I've just verified that this works via the API explorer, so it seems to be the best way to get tags onto live events with the API.

Comment: I see, thank you for this! Were tags ever supported in the creation of live broadcasts? 

Also, if possible, would you mind attaching the API calls you mentioned you tested in your answer? That would be super helpful! And of course, I'll be sure to mark it as correct :)

Comment: Also, I'm guessing it's not possible to add a video category to a live broadcast, correct?