# Youtube LiveBroadcast API - set country and tags

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

How set country details and tag details programmatically via java API (v3-rev179-1.22.0) in Youtube LiveBroadcast Event?
[here an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DffCJ.png)

Comment: About tags, maybe there is the same workaround for "country": https://stackoverflow.com/a/31399314/2154011